# Как взять нужные данные из строки, если известен её номер?

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

С помощью `bs4` хочу взять данные с определённой строчки и вывести оттуда данные.

```
<span class="wb-ba" v-mount:raw=" value " v-pre="" v-tooltip="''" v-update:raw=" value ">
0
</span>
```

Мне нужна цифра "0", которая находится на строчке 2770.

Answer (score -1):

Можете попробовать сделать так:

```
data = list(soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'wb-ba'))
info = data.text
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]